# yodlee auto debit from account

Tags: integration, yodlee

I'm new to use yodlee api. I just want to know is there any API or kind of mechanism available which,

If I transact $x amount from my debit/credit card then it will auto debit amount from the same account and will credited in yodlee.

Any help greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Once you transact X$ amount using your debit/credit card, then that transaction information will be entered in the transactions details.

Regards,

Krithik

Comment: I'm doing transactions of $x amount in lets say amazone.com & now I want some per centage of $x amount in yodlee.

Comment: In this case , we will be returning the transaction details-  transaction amount, merchant name etc.  You can refer to our data model-https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Data_Model for more information.